# Is it possible that a program uses different sizes of RAM on two different processors?

Tags: python, memory, memory-management

I have a python module. i have different observations of RAM usage when run in different machines.

1. If i run it on Ubuntu PC, it runs with 8 MB of RAM
2. If i run the same program on an ARM processor, it runs with around 15 MB RAM.

i would like to know, what are the parameters which are reasons for behavior and i would like to know if i can try to run it with 8 MB of RAM on the ARM processor too because i have only 32 MB of free RAM left there?

Is it because of cross compiled python interpreter?

Comment: There's a simple explanation if your Ubuntu PC has a 32-bit processor but the ARM is 64-bit: all the pointers on the latter are twice as big as the pointers on the former.

Comment: My Ubuntu PC is 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Same program can have different RAM usage on different processors. It depends on the processor's instruction set. e.g RISC based processors use more number of instructions for the same task than CISC based processors, hence more lines of assembly code. More lines of code means more RAM usage. So the architecture of the processor and its instruction set can have impact on the RAM usage.